# How to write xpath to get result for current active window?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have same button like Save & Close on different tab in my application. If I write XPath like **//button[contains(text(), 'Save')]** it shows result for all button with 'Save' text present on different tab either active or inactive. Is there any way to get result for 'Save' button only for currently opened active tab?

These are HTML for 'Save' button for different places. I want to write one XPath which should work for all 'Save' button so that I can use it in a method. Wanted to know is there any way to get result for presently opened tab?

1)

```
<button class="btn ng-binding btn-primary" style="margin-right:5px;" ng-class="checkDeleteCrud()" ng-click="modalActionManager()" ng-disabled="disableSaveButton()" ng-hide="crudStatus==='V'" type="button" aria-hidden="false">Save
                </button>
```

2)

```
<button class="btn ng-binding btn-primary" ng-class="checkDeleteCrud()" ng-click="modalActionManager()" ng-disabled="( notValidType() || locksavebutton || !createStatisticsForm.$dirty ) &amp;&amp; saveButtonText=='Save' " ng-hide="crudStatus==='V'" type="button" aria-hidden="false">
                                                                Save
                                                             </button>
```

3)

```
<button class="btn ng-binding btn-primary" style="margin-right:5px;" ng-class="checkDeleteCrud()" ng-click="modalActionManager()" ng-disabled="disableSaveButton()" ng-hide="crudStatus==='V'" type="button" aria-hidden="false">Save
                                        </button>
```

Comment: Share HTML for active and inactive tab

Comment: Are you actively switching tabs in your code? Something like this : `webdriver.switch_to_window(webdriver.window_handles[1])`

Comment: @Andersson I have edited my question with HTML.... Just wanted to know is there any way to get result for currently opened window(with Save button) instead of those Save button which is there on webpage but currently it is not visible as its on different window.

Comment: Which one from provided 3 buttons you want your XPath to fetch?

Comment: @Andersson Since these three save button is at different places and and cannot be visible at the same time, so I wanted to write common generic XPath which works for currently visible 'Save' button instead of writing different XPath for each separately as there are many. So is there any way for this?

Comment: Yes @Andersson it is currently visible...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something generic for visible button why not simply go with CSS Selector like :

```
button[ng-disabled*=' ']
```

If I explain currently all your disabled elements have `ng-disabled` value equal to `disableSaveButton()` but the active element doesn't have this function but contains data with spaces so I will look in any spaces within `button` `ng-disabled` data simple.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Hi, this css(button[ng-disabled*=' ']) does not give any result.

Comment: When I opened the different window which has 'Save' button mentioned in above HTML(2nd one), it shows two matches.

Comment: Can you update the better html view as this is angular app. Also it is difficult to understand the word window. Is it a pop-up, or element in new tab. Please Update how dom element changes for element when it came to active state too.

Answer (score 0):

First look for the active tab, for this you need to know how the active tab in the Dom differs from non-active tabs. Then look in this element for a button with the text "Save". Use a dot as the first character in your XPath expression.

Let say webelement "tab" is the active tab then you can find the button as follows (C# code):

```
tab.FindElement(ByXPath(".//button[contains(text(),'Save')]")
```